# Is there any way if we can create Enum in Postgres DB using JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm following link: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/. Is there any way if we can create Enum in Postgres DB using JPA?

```
CREATE TYPE MyStatus AS ENUM (
    'PENDING',
    'APPROVED',
    'SPAM'
)
```

I really don't want to keep it manual execution. Any way of doing this?

I'm looking out the way to create everything using FlyWay. There are certain reasons for that. Do you know if creation of Enum using JPA possible ? I think this feature should be available as JPA gives almost everything

I used below in my model class, but still it doesn't works well.

```
@Column(name = "status", length = 1, columnDefinition = "MyStatus")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@MapKeyEnumerated
@Type( type = "pgsql_enum" )
private StatusEnum status;
```

Comment: The question is if you want to continue to create the DB schema with JPA or if you want to switch to DB migrations and use FlyWay or Liquibase. The advantage of DB migrations is that you have the full control over the generated SQL and from my experience the DB lives longer than the app

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - I'm looking out the way to create everything using FlyWay. There are certain reasons for that. Do you know if creation of Enum using JPA possible ? I think this feature should be available as JPA gives almost everything

Comment: JPA maps classes and attributes to tables and columns. But Hibernate allows to do a lot. Check out the docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - I used as per mentioned in the doc, but doesn't seem working. Please check my updated post

Comment: No you didn't because there is no code that will generate the DB type. You have to use custom SQL like in the doc

Comment: I think, Enum is the only type it look like doesn't get created automatically, as it happened with the other types. Then it seem its not possible to use Flyway approach here

Comment: Yes because not all databases know enums plus JPA stores enums not as enums but as String or Integer value. But why do you think FlyWay cannot be used? With Flyway you define all DDL statements there is no generation happen

Comment: What is the problem you are having?